# ServerClick event in .NET on button click

Tags: asp.net, button, onclick, buttonclick

I am trying to fire ServerClick event in .NET on button click. 
it works fine if I don't add onclick="return ValidateForm();"

```
<button runat="server" id="btn1" type="submit" onclick="return ValidateForm();">SAVE</button>
```

I have already declared a javascript function in head as below:

```
<script>
    function ValidateForm(){
        //some validation code, return true/false
        return true;
    }
</script>
```

Below button also works fine:

```
<button runat="server" id="btn1" type="submit" onclick="return true;">SAVE</button>
```

but if I add onclick="return somefunction" its not working.

What I am doing wrong ?

Thanks

Comment: How is the title related to your question?

Comment: Sorry, system picked that wrong title from cookies and I did not noticed it. I have changed the title.

Comment: did u try add your function inside $(document).ready();

Comment: set type as well in script tag ``<script type="text/javascript">``

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change your markup to:

```
<button runat="server" id="btn1" type="submit" onclick="if( !ValidateForm() ) return false;" onserverclick="btn1_click">SAVE</button>

<script>
function ValidateForm() {
    //some validation code, return true/false
    return true;
}
</script>
```

- don't forget that semi-colon at end of onlick attribute; If you inspect the result HTML code you will know why !

Assuming you have the click handler in code behind C# :

```
protected void btn1_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
}
```

or VB:

```
Protected Sub btn1_click(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs)
End Sub
```